# debian-installer: report setup progress

Tags: debian, system-installation

Can I, using preseed, make the debian installer report its progress to a server?

I'd imagine something like calling `wget http://x.tld/stage_finished.php?s=partitioning_completed` to report the progress.

Right now, I have to wait until the `late_command` hook to implement a progress report, but that's called just after the setup is finished.

Answer (score 1):

What you can probably do, is to write your own d-i udeb and load it via preseed, and use it to call and external URL as you requested. But you may only hook it in `/lib/debian-installer.d/` `/usr/lib/base-installer.d/` `/usr/lib/post-base-installer.d/` `/usr/lib/pre-pkgsel.d/` `/usr/lib/finish-install.d/`. So, basically, you only get a few fixed hooks. More information on [d-i Available hooks](http://d-i.alioth.debian.org/doc/internals/apb.html)